# Phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect doesn't work

Tags: java, android, cordova

I got some problems when I try to integrate the plugin "Phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect" in to my application. I'm new with android developement and phonegap so i think it's some form of newbie mistake :) I have followed the readme that's in the plugin but not getting it to work =/

**Errors**

```
The method onCancel() of type new Facebook.DialogListener(){} must override a superclass method ConnectPlugin.java  /x/src/com/facebook/phonegap    line 92 Java Problem

    The method onComplete(Bundle) of type new Facebook.DialogListener(){} must override a superclass method ConnectPlugin.java  /x/src/com/facebook/phonegap    line 61 Java Problem

    The method onError(DialogError) of type new Facebook.DialogListener(){} must override a superclass method   ConnectPlugin.java  /x/src/com/facebook/phonegap    line 86 Java Problem

    The method onFacebookError(FacebookError) of type new Facebook.DialogListener(){} must override a superclass method ConnectPlugin.java  /x//src/com/facebook/phonegap   line 80 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your project properties, select the [Java Compiler] node, and change the [Compiler compliance level] option to 1.6 .

That should sort your issue out.

Comment: Thanks, but i got new problem. I use the example files and when i try to press login.. etc nothing happens. Just if i press "get session" then it returns null.